# Counting number of object properties with a name filter

Tags: javascript, properties, count, key

I have an object which looks like:

```
{a: 1, b:2, c:3, cp1:6, cp2:7 cp3:8, cp4:9}
```

I'm interested in the number of cpX occurrences in my Object, is there an easy way in Javascript (or jQuery) to count the number of occurrences matching a pattern. Something like:

```
Object.keys(myObj,/cp\d+/).length();
```

I know I can iterate over it myself, but I wouldn't be surprised if this functionality is already present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys()` doesn't support to filter array items. But you can use the jQuery's `grep()` function to filter your keys.

This one works:

```
var x = {a: 1, b:2, c:3, cp1:6, cp2:7, cp3:8, cp4:9};
var cpItemsLength = $.grep(Object.keys(x), function(n) { 
    return /cp\d+/.test(n);
}).length;
```

Comment: This answer is not actually right. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys - here you can see all browsers list that are support this functionality. If it's okey for you - use it, but this way is not for me :)

Answer (score 2):

this might do it

```
var obj={a: 1, b:2, c:3, cp1:6, cp2:7 cp3:8, cp4:9};
var num=0;
for (var key in obj) {
  if (/^cp/.test(key)) {
    ++num;
  }
}
alert(num);
```

you could probably do it using maps, but I'm not sure that there is native functionality for that

Comment: @drjerry didn't ask to do it using iteration.

Comment: using iteration is the simplest way, if there is no native functionality. @drjerry didn't prescribe iteration, but also didn't proscribe it. an implied preference was given but nothing specific

Answer (score 1):

There are no special functionality in pure javascript... Objects and arrays are so poor...

You can use [underscore lib](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#keys) for this purposes.

Code will be follow:

```
$(function(){
  var a = {a: 1, b:2, c:3, cp1:6, cp2:7, cp3:8, cp4:9};
  var result = _(a).chain().keys().select(function(key){ return key.match(/^cp/);}).value().length;
  $('#results').html(result);
});
```

Try it [here](http://jsbin.com/onocox/edit#source).

Comment: Thanks for the underscore_lib link I will investigate, however i'm a bit reluctant in including yet another javascript library. So I'll stick with the jQuery's grep.

Comment: just 3Kb of code. But functionality is great. I always use this lib for templating and workin with objects and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b:2, c:3, cp1:6, cp2:7, cp3:8, cp4:9}
var res = {}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => 
   key.includes('cp') && (res[key] = obj[key])
)
console.log(res) // {cp1: 6, cp2: 7, cp3: 8, cp4: 9}
```